# Is there any way to disable TortoiseHg windows integration?

Tags: tortoise-hg

I don't need Tortoise's icons on Windows Explorer. Is there any way to disable it?

Comment: How will you see the status of the various files then?

Comment: @Ignacio I only use the workbench for everything

Answer (score 3, accepted):

uninstall tortoise overlay in control panel > add/remove programs

Comment: Could not find such program (maybe it was changed since)

Answer (score 4):

Control Panel `->` add/remove programs `->` tortoisehg `->` change`->` repair `->` disable **Shell Extension x64/x86**

Comment: Under Windows 10, the control panel buttons are renamed slightly.  New workflow is the same up through `tortoisehg -> Modify -> Change -> disable`.

Answer (score 3):

I think I can go into the `msconfig` > `startup` and disable the tortoise overlay service. I don't know if it will work, but I'll give it a try